# Angular 6 can I subscribe subscription

Tags: angular6, rxjs6

I don't quite understand how to handle observable correctly. So I have a problem with my code.

In service I have two methods:

```
verify(): Observable<any> {
  return this.http.post(some_url);
}

// and

isAuthenticated(){
  this.verify().subscribe(
    data => {return true;},
    error => {return false;})
}
```

And in guard I call isAuthenticated method and I need to get boolean from it.

```
canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot) {
  return this.auth.isAuthenticated() //?
}
```

How to handle it correctly? Should I return isAuthenticated as Observable? And subscribe in guard?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it should be something like this.

Auth service:

```
import { map } from "rxjs/operators";

isAuthenticated(){
  return this.verify().pipe(map(response => response));
}
```

Guard:

```
canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot {
    return this.auth.isAuthenticated();
}
```

Comment: return all subscription? Can you explain a little bit more how does it work?

Comment: @peryztor, canActivate should return Observable<boolean> | Promise<boolean> | boolean

Comment: oh, map. Thanks!